# Progressive Tax and Onaah

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, taxes

Is there an issue of a (halachic) government taxing individuals on the basis of their income?

Comment: for those unfamiliar with tax brackets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_bracket

Comment: Why do you think Onaah would be an issue? What (other) issues do you suspect might be relevant?

Comment: Taxes are a way of financing public goods and services. As a consumer of a public good or service there is a set price on that consumption one can place a value on. However with tax brackets, different people are charged different prices for a homogeneous service(s) offered to everyone.

Comment: I would recommend adding the caveat hat you are looking for sourced answers, or halakhic issues. That prevents users from posting their respective musings on the morality of tax brackets.

Answer (score 2):

It is permitted for a halochik government to tax individuals on the basis of their "income" (how much money they own)

(at least in certain cases) (maybe it is becouse it is like tzedoko)

As can be seen from these sources regarding city government

choshen mishpat [163.3](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.163.1?lang=en) ([tzuras Hadaf](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=cm_x10382))

Shulchan aruch harav [hilchos Talmud Torah 1.3](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/1/3.htm)

PS how much a husband needs to support his wife is also based on how much money he has